# How to configure pidgin-sipe in Empathy?

Tags: empathy, pidgin-sipe

I couldn't find a way to add SIPE to Empathy in Ubuntu 12.10. I installed pidgin-sipe but I don't see the protocol in the empathy list of protocols.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1092962/25639 works for me  (some people say they have to start `empathy-accounts` from the command line though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression in the newest form of Empathy. Say this bug affects you to get it fixed:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/1070377

Comment: As an workaround, try running `empathy-accounts` in the terminal.